# Dealing with recently decarpeted room with generational urine reek

Tags: floor, safety, smell, primer

Zinsser BIN primer applied with a paint sprayer, completely covering the floor and probably the baseboards, too.  Two coats at appropriate intervals. If it oversprays to the walls, I don’t really care. If the difference is too glaring I can always paint it, the room is only 11.5x11.5.

BIN is nasty stuff, I know. I’ll have 2 out of 3 windows open. Hooded coverall, gloves, goggles.

Here’s the safety bit — I have a p100 ventilator but no VOC filters. Couldn’t find the right kind in stores. Picked up a 3m P95 mask that says it’s for nuisance VOC.

Is it safe to use either of those,  or should I order VOC filters for the ventilator?  (It’s a slim fit thing, I got it when I was scraping down efflorescence  on the basement walls. Standard canister stuff doesn’t fit it). That’ll take a few days if I do.

Comment: This could be like one paragraph long if distilled to the relevant parts only.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer myself as *Aloysius Defenestrate* already did, I have plenty of experience with the Zinsser Odor Block for this exact reason, excellent product. Would highly recommend. It goes on white and dries clear. Completely eliminated the urine odor from a saturated subfloor - 3 small dogs that kept pissing inside.

Comment: This would be an excellent question if it were edited down to just what's germane to the problem.

Comment: I gave up reading after two paragraphs ... there is no reason for useless information, such as the color of the room, or the paint style

Comment: So sorry for wasting so many people’s time. 

I’ve distilled it into a tanka form as thanks for your comments on the matter: 

The floor’s full of piss. / 
I bought Zinnser Bin primer. / 
How do I not die? / 
Do I need a VOC-blocking / 
Respirator to survive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- By my reading in the past, the enzymatic urine products take a huge, pricey volume of the stuff to work. Be sure to price out how much you'll need, as you might better spend that money elsewhere. Or just use it in the "really bad" areas where smelly surface versus non-smelly surface is obvious.
- Pet urine tends to be concentrated around room perimeters. If you don't know exactly where the smell is coming from, then put a little extra effort into the room perimeters.
- You want to get paint onto the floor area behind the baseboard moldings, so remove any baseboard molding. As long as they're loose anyway, go ahead and work them at a nice working elevation until the smell is gone. Consider installing new baseboard molding.
- Spray up the walls a foot or two. This is probably a better use of the paint than in the center of rooms.
- Pets especially love the door openings, so remove the door trim to paint the hidden drywall edges beside the door casings. For varnished wood door casings I cut paper plates in half, load them with oil-based polyurethane, and knife them underneath the door casings to seal the end grain. Last time it took something like 10 iterations to finally kill the smell, but finally worked.
- Oil based Kilz (probably not the low VOC stuff and certainly not the water based stuff) is a cheaper option than the BIN. It works, but the trade off is that the smell lingers for about 3 well-ventilated days versus BIN's less than 1 day.
- Put down vapor barrier below your flooring even if the manufacturer says that there's no need. This may be the only mitigation for any smells emanating from between your floor boards. With those gaps, you might even tuck a bit of slack under the drywall and then staple an inch or two to the wall for the baseboard molding to ultimately pinch against the wall.

Comment: Re #1: I've not had to use excessive amounts of the stuff. As I say, it does need to make direct contact, but I've even been able to use it on a rug (removing evidence of a prior occupant's toy puddle, sic) by using a carpet cleaning machine to make sure it got thoroughly soaked.  But yes, depending on how much has soaked into and flowed into the materials of the house, you may find that another approach is necessary. I don't have experience with the painting approach so can't comment.

Comment: @keshlam, I've never even tried the stuff. I was dissuaded by reviews. They weren't the "[I'm a big ol' dummy, so ignore me]" type that I constantly have to filter through on Amazon, but without direct experience with the stuff I defer to you.

Comment: Don't think I necessarily agree with the idea that pets don't tend to make use of any space available when _it's time_. ]

Comment: @gnicko, between the last two cleanups, there was maybe 3 spots outside the 2'-6" perimeter and dozens and dozens otherwise. Those were both dog houses. Maybe that makes the difference?

Comment: @popham Small dogs hiding behind the furniture while larger, more self-confident dogs prefer the additional space in the center of the room?

Comment: @gnicko, last one was a pitbull. Nice try, though. And stop this chattering. You're gonna get us in trouble. If anyone asks, I tried to stop you.

Comment: First off, thank you for the excellent suggestions! 

Having seen the bottom of the carpet, I can say with confidence that the only places that weren’t defiled were directly in the vicinity of the door to the room. Stuff by the laundry may not have been, enough old detergent in the carpet there it wouldn’t have shown easily. It was truly revolting.

Comment: The enzymatic products also have their own stink.

Comment: The kind I typically use and will use here (unscented “anti-icky-poo” spray) has a very minimal scent, and it’s not unpleasant, more like plain soap than anything else. The other kind I use (for fabric), bac-out smells like limes.

Comment: Enzyme stuff on the worst parts took it from vomit inducing stench down to a faint but detectable smell. 
First coat of BIN wiped it out completely so far as my human schnoz can detect. 

Had to take a break after that for travel etc, but planning to brush it over the nails and the worst spots this evening. This weekend, I'll a second coat. I'll add a vapor barrier and thin plywood the following week, and 3.2mm sheet vinyl to finish it off the weekend before Christmas.  I can't easily replace the 8 inch molding, but I knocked off the quarter round, I'll replace that once the vinyl is down.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, get the organic vapors cartridge for your mask.

It wasn’t crystal clear — if you haven’t removed the 1/4” hardboard, I suggest you do that.

I’d also consider pulling the baseboards to get primer behind them.

Zinsser makes a specific primer for odors. I haven’t used it, but in your shoes I would. That said, I’ve had good short term results with Bin. (Can’t speak to how long the smell was abated.)

Comment: I have experience with the Zinsser Odor Block primer and can vouch for it. One of my last projects involved removing a bunch of carpet from a home that had 3 small dogs that urinated all over the place. Removing the carpet and the ammonia smell was so bad if would make your eyes burn. I applied a single coat of the Zinsser Odor block and it was gone the next day. That product goes on white and dries clear. I still have some left from that job, excellent product.

Comment: Thanks! I have some of the odor blocking stuff to use on a downstairs bathroom - it’s tile, I don’t want to screw with ripping it apart, there’s urine soaked into the grout, and since that dries clear I figured it would work. Just haven’t done it yet. 
From the stuff I’d read before buying the BIN, the odor blocker works well, but BIN works better. That’s just from random internet posts, and chatGPT. Zinsser’s site is less than helpful.

Comment: Too late to edit. I was really hoping to avoid removing the hardboard. It’s not very hard anymore and may need to be scraped off in places. I’ll give it a try since you suggest it. Maybe I can do that, coat the actual wood, seal up the gaps somehow, put down a vapor shield, and put new hardboard or whatever over that. Would that make sense?  I have a half gallon of the primer and was told 1.5 quarts would be enough to do the floor and the first foot or two of the walls twice over, so I could paint over new hardboard and putty or caulk any gaps to help, too.

Comment: New smooth subfloor (thin ply would be my pick) would be good for whatever you cover it with. Not 100% convinced that 1/2 gallon will do it, but give it a shot. Depending on the gaps, spray foam after paint might help.

Comment: Half gallon was stupid. I had 1/3 of the floor covered before the sprayer was sucking air. Bit the bullet and bought a 5 gallon. Plenty of other places I can use whatever's left over. 
Gave up on removing the hardboard, can't afford to replace the 8 inch tall baseboard but tore out the quarter roundand will replace that after the vapor barrier, subfloor, and sheet vinyl flooring is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Pet stores sell enzyme products which react with organic does to neutralize them. They aren't expensive, they work, and are probably your best bet. My one concern is that they have to come in contact with the source of the odor, so depending on how much things soaked in you may have to apply enough if this stuff for it to soak in.

(Not just for pet smells; I've used it on human sick-room smells too.)

Comment: For the enzyme cleaner, I have two gallons of unscented “anti-icky-poo” concentrate, about $75 worth, and I’m not afraid to use it! :) It’s worked well on area rugs. If it wasn’t that I don’t want it leaving a stain on the dining room ceiling, I’d splash both gallons until the floor was saturated. So maybe I am afraid to use it, a bit. ‍♂️

Comment: Once I had everything torn up and could see the spots that were the worst, I saturated those twice and it helped a fair bit with the overall stench. Didn't really take that much of the concentrate, either. :)  

First coat of paint knocked it out completely, at least to my nose, so maybe it was redundant, but I'm fine with belt-and-suspenders.